# Google Script problems

Tags: google-apps-script

Sorry for my English and for my code, im not a programmer but I always trying something new on google script to make my sheets working better.

I made one code but isn’t working as I expect. If someone can help me i will be very thankful.

The problem is that I got 3 functions, and when I execute the 1 or the 2 alone works good. But the 3 one that it’s just the union of the first two, the msg box and “if’s” on the first function doesn’t work.

Look:

If I execute the FinalizarContrato, the function dosnt show any msgbox or check the empty fields, just run with the blank fields.

Can someone explain me and help me to correct?

Thanks!

```
function ContratoxBD() {

  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (); // Simplifica o comando
  
  //Cria variáveis de acordo com as abas.
  var contrato = planilha.getSheetByName("CONTRATO")
  var bdcontratos = planilha.getSheetByName("BD - CONTRATOS")
  var fluxodecaixa = planilha.getSheetByName("FLUXO DE CAIXA")
  var tabelas = planilha.getSheetByName("TABELAS")



  //Cria variáveis pegando o valor da próxima linha (preenchidos na aba tabelas)
  var proximalinhafluxodecaixa = tabelas.getRange('C2')
  var linhafluxodecaixa = proximalinhafluxodecaixa.getValue()

  var proximalinhabdcontratos = tabelas.getRange('C3')
  var linhabdcontratos = proximalinhabdcontratos.getValue()



  //Cria variáveis de acordo com a posição na aba contrato
  var datavenda = contrato.getRange("B2");
  var nome = contrato.getRange("B3");
  var cpf = contrato.getRange("B4");
  var servico = contrato.getRange("B5");
  var valor = contrato.getRange("B6");
  var cirurgia = contrato.getRange("B7");
  
  //Cria variáveis de acordo com o lugar onde irá colar os dado na aba bd contratos
  var colarnomebd = "A" + linhabdcontratos
  var colarcpfbd = "B" + linhabdcontratos
  var colarservicobd = "C" + linhabdcontratos
  var colarvalorbd = "D" + linhabdcontratos
  var colardatavenda = "E" + linhabdcontratos
  var colarcirurgiabd = "F" + linhabdcontratos

  //cria variáveis de acordo com o lugar onde irá colar os dado na aba fluxo de caixa
  var colaritemfl = "E" + linhafluxodecaixa
  var colarvalorfl = "F" + linhafluxodecaixa
  var colarcirurgiafl = "G" + linhafluxodecaixa

  // cria variáveis de acordo com o lugar onde irá escrever as fórmulas na aba bd contratos
  var item = bdcontratos.getRange("G" + linhabdcontratos)
  var valorpago = bdcontratos.getRange("H" + linhabdcontratos)
  var saldo = bdcontratos.getRange("I" + linhabdcontratos)
  
//**************************************************************************************** */

  //Condições se algum valor do contrato estiver vazio, mostrar erro

  if (datavenda.getValue() == "") {

    Browser.msgBox("Preencher o Campo Data da Venda!")
    datavenda.activate();

    return false

  }

  if (nome.getValue() == "") {

    Browser.msgBox("Preencher o Campo Nome!")
    nome.activate();

    return false

  }

    if (cpf.getValue() == "") {

    Browser.msgBox("Preencher o Campo CPF!")
    cpf.activate();

    return false

  }

      if (servico.getValue() == "") {

    Browser.msgBox("Preencher o Campo Serviço!")
    servico.activate();

    return false

  }

    if (valor.getValue() == "") {

    Browser.msgBox("Preencher o Campo Valor!")
    valor.activate();

    return false

  }

    if (cirurgia.getValue() == "") {

    Browser.msgBox("Preencher o Campo Código Data da Cirurgia!")
    cirurgia.activate();

    return false

  }

  //caixa de mensagem confirmando ação
  var response = Browser.msgBox("Confirmar Ação","Deseja confirmar importação do contrato?",Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response == "cancel") return;
  else
  
  //adiciona nova linha na aba bdcontratos e fluxo de caixa
  bdcontratos.insertRowAfter(linhabdcontratos-1);

  //copiar dados do contrato e colar apenas valores na aba bd contratos
  datavenda.copyTo(bdcontratos.getRange(colardatavenda),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  nome.copyTo(bdcontratos.getRange(colarnomebd),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  cpf.copyTo(bdcontratos.getRange(colarcpfbd),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  servico.copyTo(bdcontratos.getRange(colarservicobd),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  valor.copyTo(bdcontratos.getRange(colarvalorbd),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  cirurgia.copyTo(bdcontratos.getRange(colarcirurgiabd),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);

  //colocar as fórmulas na aba bd contratos
    item.setFormula("=IF(A"+linhabdcontratos+"=\"\";\"-\";A"+linhabdcontratos+"&\" \"&B"+linhabdcontratos+")");
    valorpago.setFormula("=IF(A"+linhabdcontratos+"=\"\";\"-\";SUMIFS('FLUXO DE CAIXA'!F:F;'FLUXO DE CAIXA'!E:E;G"+linhabdcontratos+";'FLUXO DE CAIXA'!I:I;\"OK\"))");
    saldo.setFormula("=IF(A"+linhabdcontratos+"=\"\";\"-\";D"+linhabdcontratos+"-H"+linhabdcontratos+")");
                        
 //limpar campos preenchidos do contrato
  contrato.getRange("B2").clear({contentsOnly:true,skipFilteredRows:true})
  contrato.getRange("B3").clear({contentsOnly:true,skipFilteredRows:true})
  contrato.getRange("B4").clear({contentsOnly:true,skipFilteredRows:true})
  contrato.getRange("B5").clear({contentsOnly:true,skipFilteredRows:true})
  contrato.getRange("B6").clear({contentsOnly:true,skipFilteredRows:true})
  contrato.getRange("B7").clear({contentsOnly:true,skipFilteredRows:true})

  // ativa e deixa o cursor na guia contrato - nome
  contrato.getRange("B2").activate();

  //mostra mensagem de finalização
  Browser.msgBox("Contrato Importado com Sucesso!")

  //esconder a aba tabelas
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Pega todas as abas ativas
  var tabelas = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("TABELAS")); //Ativa a aba "Tabelas"
  
  tabelas.activate()
  tabelas.hideSheet()
  
  //esconder a aba bd contratos
  var guiacambio = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("BD - CONTRATOS")); //Ativa a aba "BD CONTRATOS"
  
  bdcontratos.activate()
  bdcontratos.hideSheet()

}

function BDxFluxo() {

  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (); // Simplifica o comando
  
  //Cria variáveis de acordo com as abas.
  var contrato = planilha.getSheetByName("CONTRATO")
  var bdcontratos = planilha.getSheetByName("BD - CONTRATOS")
  var fluxodecaixa = planilha.getSheetByName("FLUXO DE CAIXA")
  var tabelas = planilha.getSheetByName("TABELAS")



  //Cria variáveis pegando o valor da próxima linha (preenchidos na aba tabelas)
  var proximalinhafluxodecaixa = tabelas.getRange('C2')
  var linhafluxodecaixa = proximalinhafluxodecaixa.getValue()

  var ultimalinhabdcontratos = tabelas.getRange('C4')
  var linhabdcontratos = ultimalinhabdcontratos.getValue()

  //Cria variáveis de acordo com a posição na aba BD Contratos
  var servico = bdcontratos.getRange("C" + linhabdcontratos)
  var datavenda = bdcontratos.getRange("E" + linhabdcontratos)
  var cirurgia = bdcontratos.getRange("F" + linhabdcontratos)
  var item = bdcontratos.getRange("G" + linhabdcontratos)

  //Cria variáveis de acordo com o lugar onde irá colar os dado na fluxodecaixa
  var colaritem = "E" + linhafluxodecaixa
  var colarcirurgia = "G" + linhafluxodecaixa
  var colarservico = "D" + linhafluxodecaixa
  var colarvenda = "H" + linhafluxodecaixa

  // cria variáveis de acordo com o lugar onde irá escrever as fórmulas na aba fluxodecaixa
  var categoria = fluxodecaixa.getRange("C" + linhafluxodecaixa)
  var classificacao = fluxodecaixa.getRange("D" + linhafluxodecaixa)
  var valorfluxo = fluxodecaixa.getRange("F" + linhafluxodecaixa)
  var mesref = fluxodecaixa.getRange("H" + linhafluxodecaixa)
  var status = fluxodecaixa.getRange("J" + linhafluxodecaixa)

  //adiciona nova linha na aba fluxo de caixa
  fluxodecaixa.insertRowAfter(linhafluxodecaixa-1);

  //copiar dados do bd contratos e colar apenas valores na aba fluxodecaixa
  item.copyTo(fluxodecaixa.getRange(colaritem),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  cirurgia.copyTo(fluxodecaixa.getRange(colarcirurgia),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  servico.copyTo(fluxodecaixa.getRange(colarservico),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  datavenda.copyTo(fluxodecaixa.getRange(colarvenda),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);

  //colocar as fórmulas na aba fluxodecaixa
    valorfluxo.setFormula("=VLOOKUP(E"+linhafluxodecaixa+";'BD - CONTRATOS'!G:I;3;0)");
    status.setValue("Previsto");
    categoria.setValue("Receita");


}


function FinalizarContrato() {

  ContratoxBD();
  BDxFluxo();

}
```

Comment: In your case you can probably resolve the issue by ending each function with SpreadsheetApp.flush().  But you could benefit greatly from reading google apps script best practices.   Focus on minimizing the use of getValue() in lieu of using getValues() where applicable.  Also avoid the use of setActiveSheet and activate()

Comment: Thanks Cooper. I will study these topics!